# Subversion Edge Security Failure?

Tags: security, svn, subversion-edge

I've kept my Subversion Edge upgraded with the most recent binaries, whenever the latest release was I did it. I just created a new user and went to add him to the repository access rules and noticed that my old rules were gone....the new rule was

```
[/]
* = rw
```

Someone please tell me I'm unique to experiencing this?

EDIT:
I found in `csvn/data/conf` my old access rules as `svn_access_file.bkp`